# Реализация поиска на странице с помощью фильтрации массива, не обращая внимания на раскладку клавиатуры VUE JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Есть функция для поиска. Сейчас фильтрация идет по словам с соответствующей  языковой раскладкой клавиатуры. Хотелось бы функцию дополнить: даже если в поиск попадает слово с английской раскладкой, а в массиве данных слова русские, фильтровать массив точно также. Например, при вводе в форме слова "ghbdtn", массив фильтровался и понимал, что я имела в виду "привет"

```js
let filtered = this.movies;
                filtered = this.movies.filter(
                m => m.film.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.search) > -1);
            
        return filtered;
```

Comment: А если я на немецком напишу, должно ли находиться?

Comment: Я конкретно прописала про РАСКЛАДКУ клавиатуры, про язык я ничего не говорила.  практически - реализовать можно подобное с 2 языками спокойно: русский и английский, допустим (англ. международный язык же, практически всем понятен). Такого рода фильтрация сейчас на любом поисковике, где независимо от раскладки клавиатуры, фильтр покажет все равно тебе то, что ты и хотел (независимо от раскладки опять же). Вопрос как раз и есть в том, как можно дополнить функцию поиска, чтобы у меня работал фильтр в любом случае

Comment: Дак это надо написать проверку на соответствие каждой клавиши кирилических букв на англ буквы на клавиатуры. Вот вам подсказка, а дальше на самом деле ничего тяжелого, но мне лично лень писать, извините)

Comment: @nbelle напишите функцию которая будет делать проверку, а потом слова конвертить англ на рус и дальше должно быть понятно.

Comment: Хорошо, у меня на клавиатуре установлены 3 раскладки. Русская, английская, немецкая. Нужно ли для немецкой раскладки искать?

Comment: @SonicMyst  я не прошу код, мне нужен был лишь совет, в какую сторону идти дальше) 
я человек безопытный, 3 недели в сумме занимаюсь, включая и верстку, дальнейшую работу программы (скрипта). Поэтому понимание есть, но далеко не понимание ВСЕГО. На начальном этапе вопросы - это нормально) Советы важнее, а на практике сама разберусь, полезнее будет.
спасибо!

Comment: @nbelle я и написал в какую сторону идти, а кто будет писать мне лично без разницы) Ну вот ответ уже есть подобный.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать эту функцию!

```
function auto_layout_keyboard( str ) {
        replacer = {
            "q":"й", "w":"ц", "e":"у", "r":"к", "t":"е", "y":"н", "u":"г",
            "i":"ш", "o":"щ", "p":"з", "[":"х", "]":"ъ", "a":"ф", "s":"ы",
            "d":"в", "f":"а", "g":"п", "h":"р", "j":"о", "k":"л", "l":"д",
            ";":"ж", "'":"э", "z":"я", "x":"ч", "c":"с", "v":"м", "b":"и",
            "n":"т", "m":"ь", ",":"б", ".":"ю", "/":"."
        };     

        return str.replace(/[A-z/,.;\'\]\[]/g, function ( x ){
            return x == x.toLowerCase() ? replacer[ x ] : replacer[ x.toLowerCase() ].toUpperCase();
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать такие функции для смены раскладки в обе стороны

```typescript
const EN_LAYOUT = '`1234567890-=qwertyuiop[]\\asdfghjkl;\'zxcvbnm,./~!@#$%^&*()_+QWERTYUIOP{}|ASDFGHJKL:"ZXCVBNM<>?';
const RU_LAYOUT = 'ё1234567890-=йцукенгшщзхъ\\фывапролджэячсмитьбю.Ё!"№;%:?*()_+ЙЦУКЕНГШЩЗХЪ/ФЫВАПРОЛДЖЭЯЧСМИТЬБЮ,';

const mapLayouts = (sourceLayout: string, targetLayout: string): Record<string, string> => {
    if (sourceLayout.length !== targetLayout.length) {
        throw new Error('Different length of layouts');
    }

    const result: Record<string, string> = {};

    for (let i = 0; i < sourceLayout.length; i++) {
        result[sourceLayout[i]] = targetLayout[i];
    }

    return result;
};

const EN_RU_MAP = mapLayouts(EN_LAYOUT, RU_LAYOUT);
const RU_EN_MAP = mapLayouts(RU_LAYOUT, EN_LAYOUT);

const switchLayout = (source: string, layoutMap: Record<string, string>): string => {
    return Array.from(source)
        .map((char) => layoutMap[char] ?? char)
        .join('');
};

const switchEnToRu = (source: string) => switchLayout(source, EN_RU_MAP);

const switchRuToEn = (source: string) => switchLayout(source, RU_EN_MAP);
```